# User cannot see "Shares" relationship on Case

Tags: apex-managed-sharing

I'm trying to use Apex Managed Sharing to create share records when a record is created, but I'm running into a bit of an issue when Customer Community Plus Login Users create the records...

A user with a Customer Community Plus Login license is unable to see the Shares relationship on the Case object.

```
@isTest
static void CustomerCommunityPlusLoginUserShouldBeAbleToSeeTheSharesChildObject(){
    String objectName = 'Case';
    SObjectType shareObjectType;
    Test.startTest();
    System.runAs((User)[select Id from User where IsActive = true and UserType = 'PowerCustomerSuccess' limit 1]){
        for(ChildRelationship childRelationship : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().getChildRelationships()){
            if(childRelationship.getRelationshipName() == 'Shares'){
                shareObjectType = childRelationship.getChildSObject();
                break;
            }
        }          
    }
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertNotEquals(null, shareObjectType);
}
```

This test method will fail with: "System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Same value: null"

I would really like it to find the Share object with these users... Is there a reason for this, or a way that I can change/fix this?

Comment: can you run your class as [without sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm)

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, even when the class has the without sharing keyword, the user is unable to see the sharing object type.

Comment: @arucker Share objects are not available for Customer Community Plus licenses and thus such Users. Refer to the question mentioned in the above comments and the related documentation as how you can achieve that use case.

Comment: @JayantDas, so,  I was able to make a share record if I know the name of the share record, but it still doesn't allow me to get the SObjectType. I should be able to work with this, I just need to add the Shares SObject Name in a Custom Metadata Type rather than finding the Share object from the child relationships.

Comment: I will also need to explicitly name the parent ID and the access level fields since those can change between objects. Note: A requirement of what I'm doing is to simplify and Apex Managed Sharing, and make it all run through one batch process, so it needs to work for more than just Case sharing.